# Character 'º' é aceito pelo utf8 dentro do insert, mas não é quando uso COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql, utf-8, sql-server

Estou tentando migrar os dados de um database Firebird para um PostgreSQL versão 12.0.

Para gerar um arquivo .csv contendo os registros da tabela no Firebird, utilizo o software [FBExport](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/fbexport.php),

```
./fbexport -Sc -D /opt/firebird/bin/measures.fdb -H localhost -U sysdba -P masterkey -F /home/dani/Documents/raw_cfgpar.out -Q "SELECT * FROM CFGPAR"
```

Criei o database usando apenas o nome como parâmetro, portanto os demais foram definidos com o padrão, inclusive o parâmetro "encoding",
que de acordo com a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/multibyte.html), deve receber **utf8** através do template padrão *template1*.

```
Create database measures;
```

A tabela contém colunas como valores integer e outros varchar.

Quando tento adicionar os registros do arquivo usando a função COPY, recebo um erro no terminal:

```
COPY CFGPAR (CODIGO, PARNAME, PARVALUE, VRSCODIGO) from '/home/dani/Documents/raw_cfgpar.out' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xba
```

Mostrando que o character ° não é aceito pelo UTF8

Mas quando tento inserir um registro usando insert pelo terminal, o registro é salvo, mesmo contendo o character °.

```
INSERT INTO cfgpar (codigo, parname, parvalue, vrscodigo) VALUES (55555, 'ºªã', 'ºº', 666);
INSERT 0 1
```

```
measures=# select * from cfgpar;
 codigo | parname | parvalue | vrscodigo
--------+---------+----------+-----------
  66666 | testeãº | teste    |       555
  55555 | ºªã     | ºº       |       666
(2 rows)
```

Preciso converter o arquivo csv gerado pelo FBExport para outro formato? como converter?

Comment: Já tentou explicitar o encoding? Acho que o postgre utiliza outra codificação padrão. Assim: `COPY CFGPAR (CODIGO, PARNAME, PARVALUE, VRSCODIGO) from '/home/dani/Documents/raw_cfgpar.out' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8';` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-copy.html

Comment: Tentei agora, o erro continua o mesmo, invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xba

Comment: De acordo com a referência abaixo, o caracter `0xba` está em `ISO-8869-1`, não em `UTF8` - ele sugere converter antes da migração! Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599816/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xba-in-position-1266-invali

Comment: De acordo com padrão UNICODE: `Unicode code point: U+00BA | 
Character: º | 
UTF-8: c2 ba (hex.) | 
Name: MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR`